# Unable to supress warning message following extended precision second run of ListLogLinearPlot

Tags: plotting, bugs, warning-messages

Unable using 13.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) also seen on 12.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (May 10, 2021), and MMA version 13.1 Windows 10 to suppress pink box output around ListLogLinearPlot and warning message. Interestingly, this occured on the second time the code was run, but not the first time the code was run, such that some parameter in the ListLogLinearPlot routine is not being properly reinitialized. The trace for the error, when it occurs is:

```
Message[N::precsm, 15.9546]
N[{5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000}, 15.9546]
```

What this is doing is converting 55 decimal place integers into machine numbers, and it does not help to input them as integers with infinite precision, they get converted to machine numbers of <16 place precision anyway. It may have to do with having extended precision y-values in the plot at the same time, see below. What gives?

[image]

Nothing, block structure, Quiet, etc. works to suppress error when I use  `$MinPrecision = 55;` only changing that to `$MinPrecision=0;` which I cannot use in the remainder of my code, works as a preamble to the following code example

```
$MinPrecision = 55;
xy = {{5.`55., 
    0.0440577197159802285287831435698347138365015230619050622630249999\
9977411452125`55.}, {10.`55., 
    0.0397767351603008920529547774037456110013244540775730484884499999\
9979606327965`55.}, {15.`55., 
    0.0379735868537246582793143777075686109229095658861249757409999999\
9980530808444`55.}, {20.`55., 
    0.0403678334462315117337176898869294620204074803390080127334749999\
9979303269795`55.}, {30.`55., 
    0.0425471352074908671223890338905870945655115670604601536368499999\
9978185934116`55.}, {40.`55., 
    0.0339015764395359449229476472678576372358931627517952220530499999\
9982618542507`55.}, {60.`55., 
    0.0305579901756859750115614756458075708653225091517590606670499999\
9984332810946`55.}, {90.`55., 
    0.0280861246163397472556438416252205575127934902403037556423999999\
9985600145114`55.}, {120.`55., 
    0.0250470435300903996040446249187500507581140925931280303826249999\
9987158292677`55.}, {180.`55., 
    0.0223841158985241735674763525197601764701238934759563732787749999\
9988523585041`55.}, {240.`55., 
    0.0183718123819042096738129465733000968254391091559129796155749999\
9990580707167`55.}, {360.`55., 
    0.0146878968019123678250178253397199344135782283144445660884999999\
9992469463644`55.}, {480.`55., 
    0.0129026605646067588901884229915182025478628257672824013484749999\
9993384760543`55.}, {720.`55., 
    0.0092485984333992917727449640045634871571677543329571678337749999\
9995258211051`55.}, {1440.`55., 
    0.0055288587148662002463278480750327883199079022029169382918499999\
9997165334689`55.}};
ListLogLinearPlot[xy, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

Other than reinitializing Mathematica by quitting the kernel and then rerunning code, which gets me one, and only one error free plot, the only other thing I seem to be able to do is distract it, for example,
by adding `ListPlot[{1, 2}]` afterwords, which for some reason, does work. However, when the second plot run is `ListLogLinearPlot[{1,2}]`  rather than `ListPlot[{1,2}]` although the error box around the first plot is cleared, the same error box, message and trace occurs for the second 'ListLogLinearPlot` command.

Therefore, there is an incomplete clearing of some code setting, flag or parameter in the `ListLinearLogPlot` routine that is properly cleared when `ListPlot` is run, at least for the two Versions on two different Mac OS, one with an Intel processor and the other with an M1 chip, as well as a v13.1 MMA Windows 10 OS.

Because this is annoying, I offered a bounty for confirmation of this bug and/or the best fix or recommendation offered.

P.S. Another error I have seen concerns tick marks, with no numerical axes labeling occurring, but it was inconsistent, so there is something rather seriously wrong with the runtime code.

Comment: @cvgmt I have to edit the post, but I am curious as to which four characters you edited, please let me know for my future postings.

Comment: I only enclose your code by   ```    your code      ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted by @DanielHuber, this appears to be a bug. To work around the bug, you can use the following:

```
ListLogLinearPlot[xy, ImageSize -> Medium] /. 
  (WorkingPrecision -> x_) :> (WorkingPrecision -> Max[x, $MinPrecision])
```

[image]

Effectively, this is replacing the `WorkingPrecision->15.9546` setting of the ticks of the graphic with `WorkingPrecision->$MinPrecision` (if that is higher) to ensure that you don't get the error message.

As for why you can't block it with `Quiet` and friends: The issue is that the error doesn't occur during the evaluation of `ListLogPlot[...]`, but only when the result is converted to boxes to be displayed. And since the `Quiet` wrappers etc. are already gone at that point, the message will be printed.

Comment: As I said, I tried Quiet, it did not work. I tried Block it didn't work. I tried $\$$MinPrecision=55;...code...$\$$MinPrecision=0;...`ListLogLinearPlot`... It didn't work. I will try your other suggestion above and get back to you.

Comment: Indeed, your patch appears to work. I must wait 20 hours to award a bonus, site rules.

Answer (score 1):

Correction: If you run the following the first time, everything works as expected. Only during a second run the bug appears.

Try the following:

```
xy = {{5.`55, 
    0.0440577197159802285287831435698347138365015230619050622630249999\
9977411452125`55}, {10.`55, 
    0.0397767351603008920529547774037456110013244540775730484884499999\
9979606327965`55}, {15.`55, 
    0.037973586853724658279314377707568610922909565886124975740999999 \
9980530808444`55}, {20.`55, 
    0.0403678334462315117337176898869294620204074803390080127334749999\
9979303269795`55}, {30.`55, 
    0.0425471352074908671223890338905870945655115670604601536368499999\
9978185934116`55}, {40.`55, 
    0.0339015764395359449229476472678576372358931627517952220530499999\
9982618542507`55}, {60.`55, 
    0.0305579901756859750115614756458075708653225091517590606670499999\
9984332810946`55}, {90.`55, 
    0.0280861246163397472556438416252205575127934902403037556423999999\
9985600145114`55}, {120.`55, 
    0.0250470435300903996040446249187500507581140925931280303826249999\
9987158292677`55}, {180.`55, 
    0.0223841158985241735674763525197601764701238934759563732787749999\
9988523585041`55}, {240.`55, 
    0.0183718123819042096738129465733000968254391091559129796155749999\
9990580707167`55}, {360.`55, 
    0.0146878968019123678250178253397199344135782283144445660884999999\
9992469463644`55}, {480.`55, 
    0.0129026605646067588901884229915182025478628257672824013484749999\
9993384760543`55}, {720.`55, 
    0.0092485984333992917727449640045634871571677543329571678337749999\
9995258211051`55}, {1440.`55, 
    0.0055288587148662002463278480750327883199079022029169382918499999\
9997165334689`55}};
ListLogLinearPlot[xy, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

Comment: That does not include the `$MinPrecision=55` preamble, and does not work with it included on my platform. Try it first with that command included, please.

Comment: That does not maker any difference on my machine: MMA version 13.1 Windows 10.

Comment: I'll try it on a different platform, and different Mac OS. We'll see.

Comment: Try this, run the routine twice. I have found that it does not occur after a single run but rather the second time, also see new text in my question above. For whatever reason, and on the two Mathematica versions on vastly different Mac hardware processors, the error seems to be an uncleared runtime code switch isolated so far to the `ListLogLinearPlot` routine.

Comment: You are right, the second time the error appears. I think this is a bug. Please report it to: support@wolfram.com and let us know if they answer something interessting.

Comment: email sent to support, I will indeed let you know should anything interesting arises from my bug report.

Comment: Would you mind changing your post a bit? Someone read it and assumed it is correct and downvoted my question. Of course, random downvoting from people who do not understand a post is something that cannot be avoided, but keep in mind that I upvoted your post not because it is correct, but as an encouragement for those who would contribute and do at least some testing.

Comment: [CASE:4986152] Bug report. The response from support@wolfram.com reads in part "It does indeed appear that ListLogLinearPlot is not behaving properly. I have forwarded an issue report to our developers with the information you provided."